# spearmanr in pandas with for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas/python,

I have the following data frame, I have loads of rows, just giving an overview of the table below,

| Col1 | Date | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2018 | 20 | 15 |
| A | 02/01/2018 | 30 | 16 |
| A | 03/01/2018 | 65 | 19 |
| A | 04/01/2018 | 78 | 28 |
| A | 05/01/2018 | 52 | 95 |
| B | 03/01/2018 | 69 | 35 |
| B | 10/01/2018 | 102 | 36 |
| B | 29/01/2018 | 369 | 128 |
| C | 08/01/2018 | 32 | 995 |
| C | 12/01/2018 | 15 | 325 |
| C | 16/01/2018 | 632 | 85 |
| C | 23/01/2018 | 12 | 65 |

I am trying to calculate the spearman rank for each value if column 1,

I used this code and it worked

```py
df.groupby('Col1')[['Col2','Col3']].corr(method = 'spearman') .ix[0::2,'Col3']
```

I was trying to get the same result using a for loop, and tried this,

```py
df.groupby('Col1')[['Col2','Col3']].corr(method = 'spearman') .ix[0::2,'Col3']      
        
name = sorted(df.Col1.unique())     
for name in names:      
    pivot_bydate = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Col2' , 'Col3'] index=['COBDATE'], aggfunc=np.sum)        
    spearmanr = stats.spearmanr( Col2, Col3)        
    print (sector,stats.spearmanr(Col1,Col2))
```

can anyone point out what's wrong in the for loop please?

I was thinking the for loop will do the spearman rank for each unique value in Col1, and give me a spearman rank for each value.

Thanks

Comment: The indentation. But this is surely not your question. And is `name x` supposed to be one or two variables? It/they doesn't appear in the loop anyhow, so what is its function?

Comment: What error are you getting? There is no indentation in your code, but I don't know if that's just pasted badly or not..

Comment: `for name x in names:` should be changed as `for name_x in name:`

Comment: Hi T.....pls ignore "x", name is one variable.

Comment: Hi Nordle, when I run the code " the loop" function, I am just getting 1 spearman rank as a result, I am trying to get an individual spearman rank for A, B, C